# Find the indefinite integral related between logarithm and exponential

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate :

$\int \frac{1+\ln x-\ln^{2} x}{e^{2x}+x^{2}\ln^{2}x}e^{x}dx$

I tried use this identity :

$\int e^{g(x)}(f'(x)+g'(x)f(x))dx=f(x)e^{g(x)}+C$

I also use sub $u=\ln x$ but this sub make integral so difficult

I think integral by part is better ?

Comment: Interesting typo : *tired* instead of *tried*. I should be tired too ! This looks to be a very difficult problem (not to say more). By the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: Unlikely to be elementary. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Bln(x)-x*ln(x))%2F(e%5E(2*x)%2Bx%5E2*ln%5E2(x))*e%5Ex).

Comment: According to what  metamorphy showed, may be a typo in the problem.